# Why are ERR (Expected Reciprocal Ranking) scores not normalized?

Tags: ranking, information-retrieval

It seems to me that normalized ERR ([Expected Reciprocal Ranking](http://don-metzler.net/papers/metzler-cikm09.pdf)) scores (ERR scores of your ranking algorithm divided by ERR score calculated for the ground truth ranking) are more useful than the unscaled ERR scores, but I have not seen normalized scores being reported in the literature. Is there a good reason that the ERR scores are reported in raw rather than normalized format?